# Is it possible to force report column break on group?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, grouping

I have an 2005 SSRS report that contains two tablix controls; and the report itself has two columns. What I'd like to do is force the tablix(s) to move it's data into the second column of the report; but I don't believe this is possible. For an example, my report in design view appears such as:

```
Col A Col B Col C |    COLUMN 2
x     x     x     |
```

And I am grouping on Column A, which has another grouping not shown named "ColumnGrouping" - which I want to force to group into the second column on the SSRS report. Is this possible?

Apologies in advance if the question needs further clarification - I can expound as need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for those curious, it depends on the spacing of the columns - SSRS will do the math for you and if it decides that the width of the columns are greater than the column span, it will spill over into the next row.